# Passing parameter to AWS Glue using Java SDK from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am calling a Glue job from AWS Lambda as shown below. I have a to pass a parameter to Glue. How do I do it using below code that uses Java SDK ?

```
    AWSGlue awsGlueClient = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    StartJobRunRequest jobRunRequest = new StartJobRunRequest();
    jobRunRequest.setJobName("my_transformer");
    StartJobRunResult jobRunResult = awsGlueClient.startJobRun(jobRunRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out

> jobRunRequest.setDefaultArguments()

To create parameters map object, check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Note **--** before parameter name.

Comment: I was able to figure it out...this is how you can pass parameter to Glue using Java SDK             
               jobRunRequest.addArgumentsEntry("--Mode",mode);
               jobRunRequest.addArgumentsEntry("--Paramfile",paramfile);       And you have to define the paramters on Glue job. My issue now is figuring out the state of the job. So far I havn't been able to figure that out.